# Selenium2library Add cookie

Tags: cookies, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to login to a webpage using the robotframework

I have following testcase:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library


*** Testcases ***
Login Should Succeed When the Correct Username and Password are Entered
  Open Browser  https:XXX/login
  Input Text    j_soldTo  18999
  Input Text    j_username  testklant 18999
  Input Text    j_password    Test18999
  Click Button  Login
  Close Browser
```

The webpage has a request to accept the cookies before I'm able to click on the login button (which is grey out).
How can I use the accept cookie functionality from Selenium in this test case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I add following:

```
Click Element  Link=I accept
```

I Accept is the title of the button in orde to accept the cookies